# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Project.Models.Booking>' to Project.Models.Booking

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on school project, and I'm trying to implement asynchronous methods in my repository classes and got this error in my API for the POST-method: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to Project.Models.Booking.

Can someone please help me to solve this error?

This is how my repository-method looks like:

```
    public async Task<Booking>CreateBooking(Booking inBooking) {
        Booking booking = new Booking();

        booking.BookingId = ApplicationDbContext.Bookings.Count();
        booking.UserName = inBooking.UserName;
        booking.UserMail = inBooking.UserMail;
        booking.UserMobile = inBooking.UserMobile;
        booking.Available = false;
        booking.StartTime = inBooking.StartTime;
        booking.EndTime = inBooking.EndTime;
        booking.Date = inBooking.Date;

        Add(booking);
        return await Task.FromResult(booking);
        //return booking;
    }
```

And this how my Post-method looks like:

```
 [Route("api/PostBooking")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostBooking(BookingSystemServiceBookingViewModel inBooking)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest("Invalid data");
            }

            var booking =  inBooking.booking;

            booking.StartTime = inBooking.startTime;
            booking.EndTime = inBooking.startTime.AddMinutes(inBooking.service.Duration);

             uw.Services.AddBooking(uw.Bookings.CreateBooking(booking), inBooking.service.ServiceId);
            uw.Complete();

            return Ok();
        }
```

I get the error message at: uw.Services.AddBooking(uw.Bookings.CreateBooking(booking), inBooking.service.ServiceId);`

Comment: To return the result of a `Task<>` method you either need to `await` or `.Result`.

Comment: `uw.Services.AddBooking(await uw.Bookings.CreateBooking(booking), inBooking.service.ServiceId);`

Comment: And that is one of the reasons I follow the recommendation of adding the suffix Async at the end of my method names.... :)

Comment: The common recommendation is to append "Async" to the names of async functions. If you do, you are less likely to forgert to "await" them, as you do here.

Comment: Remove "await" from `return await Task.FromResult(booking);`, also "async" from `public async Task<Booking>CreateBooking(Booking inBooking)` and you should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> trying to implement asynchronous methods in my repository classes

The best way to make things asynchronous is not from the "outside in". That is, you don't want to start at the controller action and say "how can I make this asynchronous?". Instead, you want to start from the lowest-level API and say "this should be asynchronous" (i.e., it's I/O-based), and let asynchrony grow out from there.

If `Add` actually does the database insert, then that would be the first method to be made asynchronous. Then you `await` your `AddAsync` method, and the asynchrony grows from `AddAsync` to `CreateBookingAsync`:

```
public async Task<Booking> CreateBookingAsync(Booking inBooking) {
  Booking booking = new Booking();

  ...

  await AddAsync(booking);
  return booking;
}

[Route("api/PostBooking")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostBooking(BookingSystemServiceBookingViewModel inBooking)
{
  ...

  uw.Services.AddBooking(await uw.Bookings.CreateBookingAsync(booking), inBooking.service.ServiceId);
  uw.Complete();

  return Ok();
}
```

If, on the other hand, it is the `Complete` method that actually communicates with the database, then *that* is the one that should be made asynchronous. In this case `Add` is purely an in-memory operation, and `Complete` is the one that saves all the database updates. So, *after* you convert `Complete` to `CompleteAsync`, your code would look like:

```
public Booking CreateBooking(Booking inBooking) {
  Booking booking = new Booking();

  ...

  Add(booking);
  return booking;
}

[Route("api/PostBooking")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostBooking(BookingSystemServiceBookingViewModel inBooking)
{
  ...

  uw.Services.AddBooking(uw.Bookings.CreateBooking(booking), inBooking.service.ServiceId);
  await uw.CompleteAsync();

  return Ok();
}
```